# "There is no index available for this selector" despite the fact I made one

Tags: cloudant

In my data, I have two fields that I want to use as an index together. They are `sensorid` (any string) and `timestamp` (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss).

So I made an index for these two using the Cloudant index generator. This was created successfully and it appears as a design document.

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [
      {
    "name": "sensorid",
    "type": "string"
      },
      {
    "name": "timestamp",
    "type": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  "type": "text"
}
```

However, when I try to make the following query to find all documents with a timestamp newer than some value, I am told there is no index available for the selector:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "timestamp": {
      "$gt": "2015-10-13 16:00:00"
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "_id",
    "_rev"
  ],
  "sort": [
    {
      "_id": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me like cloudant query only allows sorting on fields that are part of the selector.
Therefore your selector should include the _id field and look like:

```
   "selector":{
      "_id":{
         "$gt":0
      },
      "timestamp":{
         "$gt":"2015-10-13 16:00:00"
      }
   }
```

I hope this works for you!